# What's the meaning of #define when there is only 2 part?

Tags: c++

I know the following 3 parts `#define`:

```
#define PI 3.4
```

which mean it will replace `PI` with `3.4`.

But that's the meaning of 2 parts `#define` like this:

```
#define something
```

Will it replace `something` with null/empty string?

The following is the code example, I searched the file, only list the related lines

```
  D:\mariadb\storage\pbxt\src\cache_xt.cc (23 hits)  
    Line 172: #ifdef xtPublic  
    Line 173: #undef xtPublic  
    Line 188: #define xtPublic  
    Line 325: xtPublic XTIndHandlePtr xt_ind_get_handle(..)  
    Line 378: xtPublic void xt_ind_release_handle(XTIndHandlePtr..)  
    Line 516: xtPublic xtBool xt_ind_copy_on_write(XTIndReferencePtr iref)  
    Line 597: xtPublic void xt_ind_lock_handle(XTIndHandlePtr handle)
```

Comment: Not really relevant here, but defining PI to 3.4 is a terrible approximation. :)

Comment: thanks, just a example, but a bad example :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it meaning replace `something` with an empty string. But the important thing is now `something` is recognized by the preprocessor that it is "defined", so

```
#ifdef something
```

will pass after that `#define` (Line 172).

Also, it is common to use it for configurational or vendor-specific attributes (Line 325, ...), like

```
#if MSVC
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT
#endif

EXPORT void f();
// expand to '__declspec(dllexport) void f()' in MSVC
// expand to 'void f()' in other compilers
```

Answer (score 1):

Those declarations are usually given within header files, as a means of preventing double inclusion of the same file. These are also called [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 1):

`#define something` will result into something just defined. It will not cause a compiler error. It is used usually like

`void getValue(IN int& x, OUT int& y)`. If you do `#define IN and #define OUT it will not give a compiler error and anybody will get to know x is input and y is output`

One more use is like

```
#ifndef __ABC_H__
#define __ABC_H__

...

#endif
```

This is to prevent reinclusion of for eg. "abc.h"

Comment: Of course, we wouldn't dare to actually use `__ABC_H__` as an identifier, because [it's reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 1):

Its is nothing but Pre-Processor Directive, the `#define` just will direct the Header files to the considered Library files or can declares the constants.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it replaces the preprocessor with empty string. It helps is self-documenting the code without writing lengthy comments.